# How do I get onRendered to run a second time when the route changes but the template remains the same?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an iron-router route for updating the data of a specific project:

```
Router.route('/project/:key/update', {
  ...
});
```

Each time the user navigates to an "edit project page" I want to focus the project-name input.

```
template.onRendered(function() {
  this.$('form input[name="project_name"]').focus();
});
```

This works great when navigating from the Dashboard to any given edit project page. However, navigating to/from one project page to another the `onRendered` function doesn't rerun and consequently the input is not focused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force [onRendered](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) to reevaluate after a context change by adding a check for [currentData](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata) inside of an [autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) like this:

```js
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  var self = this;
  this.autorun(function() {
    // hack to force the autorun to reevaluate
    Template.currentData();

    // insert onRendered code here
    self.$('form input[name="project_name"]').focus();
  });
});
```

For more details, see the end of [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2010).

Comment: Thank you! I had read your answer to a similar question on SO but I was missing the ```self``` part.